# Prepositions for "Wednesday night" and "the night of Christmas Eve"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, christmas

Which of the following prepositions would be most appropriate to be used before *Wednesday night* and *the night of Christmas Eve* when referring at exactly during these time(s) (not before or after)?

- *at* the night of Christmas Eve
- *on* the night of Christmas Eve
- *in* the night of Christmas Eve

Comment: What is the exact phrase where you would used those words?

Comment: Let us say, "We can get together x Wednesday night" and "Since there was nothing I could do I wandered in downtown x the night of Christmas Eve"

Comment: I've edited the question to include some information that was buried in a comment on the first answer.

Comment: That is great. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don’t typically use a preposition there, but if you must, *on* is the correct one, because you are basically referring to a day, or a general time period within a day:

> **on Wednesday** (night)
>   **on** (the night of) **Christmas Eve**

*At* is definitely not correct, because generally we use *at* for times, not dates. *In* is technically correct as well, because “in the night” means “during the night” or “at nighttime”, but you would still use *on* to attach a specific date:

> I heard a strange sound **in the night** on Christmas Eve.

Comment: That is the point I am mostly confused.I would use "on" before days, but I do not think it is referring to the day, rather the night of the day. This webpage says "We say in the morning, afternoon or evening BUT we say 'at night' " without mentioning this very night or any night http://esl.about.com/od/grammarintermediate/a/prepositions_of_time.htm

Comment: @Everyman: When you mention a date, use *on*. For example, “I like to go jogging in the morning” refers to a habitual action, whereas “I went jogging on the morning of the 18th” or “on Friday morning” mentions a particular day.

Comment: For British English, I would disagree with Jon's first statement: I find "I'm coming Wednesday" to be rather American. It does get used informally in the UK, but I would not write it.

Answer (score 4):

In the examples you make, there is no need to use any preposition.

> We can get together Wednesday night.
>   Since there was nothing I could do, I wandered downtown the night of Christmas Eve.

At least in American English, you can use a weekday as adverb, such as in the following sentences:

> We will try again Friday. (We will try again on Friday.)
>   See you Wednesday. (See you on Wednesday.)

This usage is reported to be chiefly North American, from the OED.

Comment: I cannot remember the questions so I made up these ones. I guess I had better get the exact questions. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't use a preposition with *downtown*, either. Second best would be "in the downtown [area]". Just "in downtown" sounds... strange.

Comment: @Marthaª I was focusing on the other part of the sentence that I didn't notice that. "I wandered downtown" sounds better to me too, considering that _wander_ can be used without object, and _downtown_ can be used as adverb.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to be rather a long list. Just considering prepositions beginning with **a** and **b**, here are some example phrases which would be appropriate:

- (on or) **about Wednesday night**
- **after Wednesday night**
- **around Wednesday night**
- **before Wednesday night**
- **besides Wednesday night**
- **between Wednesday night** (and …)
- **beyond Wednesday night**
- **by Wednesday night**

The same list will be appropriate for "the night of Christmas Eve".

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear in the question. I am referring to "during" or "exactly" at/in/on a given time.. I was supposed to choose "at", "on", or "in."